# Group By Month and Year in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the below data set consisting of cards swiped and time when swiped. The output has to be total no of cards swiped month and year wise.

```
Card No Date Time
34235   9/17/2018 5:19
56438   9/17/2018 5:57
634787  9/17/2018 5:58
79749   9/17/2018 5:59
48947   9/17/2018 6:00
3776    9/17/2018 6:07
34235   9/17/2018 6:20
56438   9/17/2018 6:23
634787  9/17/2018 6:29
79749   9/17/2018 6:35
48947   9/17/2018 6:43
3776    9/17/2018 7:05
34235   9/17/2018 7:06
56438   9/20/2018 14:25
634787  9/20/2018 14:25
79749   9/20/2018 14:26
48947   9/20/2018 14:27
3776    9/20/2018 14:28
34235   9/20/2018 14:29
56438   9/20/2018 14:32
634787  9/20/2018 14:34
79749   11/21/2018 7:58
48947   11/21/2018 8:02
3776    11/21/2018 8:02
634787  11/21/2018 8:05
79749   11/21/2018 8:11
48947   11/21/2018 8:13
3776    11/21/2018 8:20
34235   12/4/2018 14:36
56438   12/4/2018 14:37
634787  12/4/2018 14:44
79749   12/4/2018 14:44
48947   12/4/2018 14:52
3776    12/4/2018 14:54
```

Output

```
Month/Year Count
Sep/2018 21
Nov/2018 7
Dec/2018 6
```

I have tried using groupby but not able to reach the expected output.

```
  df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Card No','Date Time'])

df2 = df1.groupby([df1['Date Time'].dt.year.rename('year'), df1['Date Time'].dt.month.rename('month')).agg({'count'})
```

How do I include the month name?

Comment: SO does not gear towards teaching you how to start with pandas. You are essentially asking us to code your task. Please refere to the pandas tutorials online, start learning here: [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html)

Comment: since you're looking for a heads up, check out the `dt.strftime` accessor for your `Date_Time` column good luck!

Comment: df2 = df1.groupby([df1['Date Time'].dt.year.rename('year'), df1['Date Time'].dt.month.rename('month')).agg({'count'})

Comment: @PatrickArtner I edited the question with my partial answer . I have made progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you made an attempt - this is how I would do it for your expected output,

```
df['month_'] = df['Date Time'].dt.strftime('%b')
df['year_'] = df['Date Time'].dt.strftime('%Y')
new_df = df.groupby(["month_", "year_"])["Card_No"].count().reset_index().sort_values(
    "Card_No", ascending=False)
print(new_df)
    month_  year_   Card No
2   Sep 2018    21
1   Nov 2018    7
0   Dec 2018    6
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html for more information.

## Edit

to sort by Month you'd need some sort of integer value to work with (although some may know better)

```
    df['month_'] = df['Date Time'].dt.strftime('%m') # change %b to %m
   df['year_'] = df['Date Time'].dt.strftime('%Y')
   new_df = df.groupby(["month_", "year_"])["Card_No"].count().reset_index().sort_values(
    "month_")
```

Comment: I would like to sort by month and year . I tried by using but its not sorting as expected. new_df = df1.groupby(["month_", "year_"])["Card_No"].count().reset_index().sort_values(
    ["year_","month_"], ascending=[False,False])

Comment: it's difficult as it's an object now and not a datetime object. not really sure how to sort by month year without

Comment: Yes , its sorting by name of month but ideally it should be in the order of month

Comment: Thanks for the edit . I have one more question on this . How do I calculate the average card swipes by month. Average card swipes is equal to count of swipes for month divided by number of days in that month .

Comment: by month or month/year? does the `.mean()` method not help?

Comment: The output should be :month_year_ Card No avg
Sep-18 21 0.7
Nov-18 7 0.233333333
Dec-18 6 0.193548387

Comment: We have already got the count . How do I get the no of days in that month

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199766/discussion-between-abhishek-anand-and-datanovice).

Comment: Use `df[time].dt.year` instead of `strftime`.

Comment: @QuangHoang is there a reason why? (for readability?) as I understand both return an object instead of a datetime, and I used strftime to match the intended output. Happy to see a better alternative.

Comment: No, year/month returns numbers, which can be faster when groupby and more plot friendly.